# React Hooks to filter through list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using react/redux & would like to filter through posts that are from my backend in Node. I am mapping through the posts and they are being shown. Trying to implement a filter input I am looking for some advice on how to use react hooks to get this working.

My component...

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import { getCommunityPosts } from '../../actions/communitypost';
import CommunityPostItem from './CommunityPostItem';

import Cooking from '../../img/vegetables.jpg';
import Lifestyle from '../../img/lifestyle.jpg';
import General from '../../img/general.jpg';

// Lazy load 
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';

const CommunityPosts = ({
  getCommunityPosts,
  communitypost: { posts, loading }
}) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchPosts, setSearchPosts] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const results = posts.filter(post => {
      console.log(post);
      post.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)  
    }
    );
    setSearchPosts(results)
    getCommunityPosts();
  }, [getCommunityPosts, searchTerm]);

  return (
    loading ? (
      <Spinner />
    ) : (
      <Fragment>
      <Fragment>
        <div className="search-recipes">
          <input
            className="bg-white focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline border border-gray-300 rounded-lg py-2 px-4 block w-full appearance-none leading-normal"
            type="text"
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder="Search community posts..."
          ></input>
        </div>
        <div className="pt-1 grid lg:grid-cols-3 md:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-1 gap-1">
          <div className="cursor-pointer category-overlay">
            <Fragment>
              <Link to="/communityposts/category/cooking">
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" src={Cooking}></LazyLoadImage>
              <div className="content">
                <div className="recipe-category-text pacifico">Cooking</div>
              </div>
              </Link>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
          <div className="cursor-pointer category-overlay">
            <Fragment>
            <Link to="/communityposts/category/lifestyle">
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" src={Lifestyle}></LazyLoadImage>
              <div className="content">
                <div className="recipe-category-text pacifico">Lifestyle</div>
              </div>
              </Link>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
          <div className="cursor-pointer category-overlay">
            <Fragment>
            <Link to="/communityposts/category/general">
              <LazyLoadImage effect="blur" src={General}></LazyLoadImage>
              <div className="content">
                <div className="recipe-category-text pacifico">General</div>
              </div>
              </Link>
            </Fragment>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
      <Fragment>
        <div className="community-posts bg-gray-200">
          {posts.map(post => (
            <CommunityPostItem key={post._id} post={post} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    </Fragment>
    )

  );
};

CommunityPosts.propTypes = {
  getCommunityPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  communitypost: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  communitypost: state.communitypost
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCommunityPosts })(CommunityPosts);
```

Error i'm getting is that "TypeError: post.toLowerCase is not a function"

Comment: What is the output of console.log(post) ?

Comment: Try post.toString().toLowerCase()

Comment: What is the *actual* object shape of `communitypost`, and subsequently `posts`? This is so we can see what you are trying to operate on as a string.

Comment: You dont want to store the filtered posts in state. Just store ALL posts in state and run the filter inside the return function when you render. Otherwise you're losing posts and have to refetch them when your filter changes.

Comment: @nilankaManoj The console.log(post) outputs all of the posts as objects